# Comparing two Byte[]'s for equality in Scala (checking binary image data)

Tags: scala

I want to compare two (small) `Byte[]`'s that contain a representation of a binary image. I don't want to use MD5 or SHA or whatnot because there is no point... these just iterate the array, calculate a checksum, etc., and there is no need.

It seems there should be a super-easy way to iterate of two arrays, `a1` and `a2`, and compare them for equality, such as:

```
(a1, a2).forall(a, b => a == b)
```

But this does not work of course...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Following should do it

```
val a: Array[Byte] = Array(1,2,4,5)
val b: Array[Byte] = Array(1,2,4,5)
a.deep==b.deep
```

The other way would be

```
a.sameElements(b)
```

Comment: Thank you, perfect... both concise and elegant.

Answer (score 4):

Consider also the difference between `a1` and `a2`,

```
(a1 diff a2).isEmpty
```

which halts the comparing at the first mismatch.

Answer (score 2):

```
 val arrayOne = Array(1,2,3)
 val arrayTwo = Array(1,2,3)

 arrayOne zip arrayTwo forall {case (a,b) => a == b}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering with the `forall` I knew there was a way that would involve iterating.